# Callback from chrome custom tabs

Tags: android, fitbit, chrome-custom-tabs

I am implementing Fit-bit rest-client authorisation in my android application. I use custom tabs for opening fitbit authorization URL like "https://www.fitbit.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxx&scope=activity&redirect_uri=testing://callbackfitbit&prompt=login?time=time". What normally happens is I get Authorization code in my Activity class. But sometimes as fitbit URL is opened in custom tabs, my application is exited. I don't understand this behaviour.

No log is reported for this behaviour.

Any suggestion may help me understanding this behaviour.

Comment: I'm having the same issue

Comment: Does this help? 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084681/chrome-custom-tabs-redirect-to-android-app-will-close-the-app

Answer (score 1):

If you are integrating with an OAuth2 / OpenID Connect compliant authorization server, I would recommend [AppAuth](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android). AppAuth provides a simpler interface for performing OAuth2 authorization and token requests, and handles all the specifics of using custom tabs and routing of responses to your app. There is also an [iOS variant](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) of the library. Both are maintained by Google and the OpenID Foudnation.

Full disclosure: I'm the lead maintainer of AppAuth.