# [Android]After the google chrome update, the chrome custom tab is auto behind the background

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, fitbit, chrome-custom-tabs

I need to redirect to my custom scheme (my app) after OAuth2 authentication.
What I did before is success by follow the [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084681/chrome-custom-tabs-redirect-to-android-app-will-close-the-app)

But the problem happened again after updating the chrome browser in the android.
I ask my friend who do not update the android chrome, and it works fine such that he is using my application.
Does any one meet the same problem? What's wrong about the chrome 4.2 version 53.0.278.124)?

Answer (score 1):

After my investigation, I change the launchemode to singleinstnace and it works.

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance">
```